# check https data with firebug

Tags: https, firebug, secure-coding

is data of form encrypted over https visible with firebug?
i test it but the firebug show me the text-plain posted params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view both data sent to the server and retrieved from the server with firebug and they will be unencrypted since firebug fetches data before encryption/after decryption. You can view a sample screenshot here: [sample screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/2wc1cp0/7)

Hope this helps.

Have a nice day,
Melih.

Note: I could not attach screenshot to this message since I'm new in stackoverflow :)

Comment: thank you Melih.you confirm what i guess about my problem and welcome to here. ;)